# xcode 7 image array allocation

Tags: arrays, image, xcode7

How do I put multiple images in an empty image array in swift 2 or Xcode 7.3?

The following error keeps popping up for me:

> cannot assign a value of type 'UIImage?' to type '[UIImage]'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
imageArray = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2")]
```